# Python pivot on dataframe and return values as strings

Tags: python, pivot-table

I have a Dataframe, userID,Item and Score. I would like to get a pivot on ItemID and have top scored Items on values field. Is it possible to get Items on pivot result. Scores I can get with Max/Mean and similar methods but I couldnt figure out how to get string values.

**Here is my Dataframe:**

[image: My Dataframe]

**This is what I'm trying to achive:**

[image: What I want to achive]

Comment: Could you show what you get and what you want? It is not very clear. AFAIU, you manage to pivot your table, but then you wonder how to transform the numeric values into strings.In that case the answer is df[col] = df[col].astype(str). But I'm not sure this is what you intent to do.

Comment: I want to have Users preferred Items on pivot. My dataframe is repeating for each item and corresponding score of the user for each item as in table1. What I try to achive is pivot by UserId and Have columns for preferred Items sorted by highest score. for example users most popular item is in "Preference1" column as in table2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will create a row for each userid and create columns for items in the order of the score

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'userid': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'item': ['ford', 'renault', 'fiat', 'ford', 'jaguar'],
                   'score': [1, 5, 1, 4, 2]})
df['preference'] = df.groupby(['userid'])['score'].rank(method="first", ascending=False)
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='userid', columns="preference", values="item")
print(df_pivot)
```

If there are unequal rows for the userid then a NaN will fill the gaps.

One question is what should happen if there is a tie in the score column; in the code I wrote above I use the first row in the data frame. This means that the preference column is always 1, 2, 3, 4... within each userid group, which leads to a nicer presentation of the preference columns.